# Using EL as parameters for layout-macro expressions

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Trying to use EL to generate a that takes a variable as input into a layout-macro -> param -> expression/literal. but it keeps giving me compile errors or inputting the literal of my EL.

Is there a way to do this at the moment?

```
layout-macro-def (game-details) {
  params {
    param (game) {
      type (Game)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
// [...]
        for-each (game.external_games) {
          as (item) {
            switch (item.category) {
              case (1) { // Steam
                layout-macro (UriButton) {
                  param (url) { // <<----- Expression for this is giving me issue
                    expression ("https://store.steampowered.com/app/#{value(item.uri)}")
                  }
                  param (image) {
                    literal (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/354331388142419988/567499944391344158/unknown.png)
                  }
                  param (name) {
                    literal ("Steam")
                  }
                }
              }
// [...]
```

Edit added context

the layout-macro

```
layout-macro-def (UriButton) {
  params {
    param (url) {
      type (URL)
      min (Required)
    }
    param (image) {
      type (URL)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
    param (name) {
      type (Name)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }

  content {
    cell-card {
      on-click {
        intent {
          goal: UriRedirect
          value: UriRedirect {
            url {$expr(url)} // <--- Ultimate goal URL with URI appended to the end
            }
        }
      }
      slot1 {
        image {
          shape (Square)
          url ("#{value(image)}")
        }
      }
      slot2 {
        content {
          primary ("#{value(name)}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you were putting a template where an expression was expected. Templates contain expressions (inside the #{}) but they aren’t expressions themselves.

Use a template as below.

```
layout-macro (UriButton) {
  param (url) {
    dialog-template {
    template ("https://store.steampowered.com/app/#{value(item.uri)}")
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh interesting; But now it's throwing me an error on 'dialog-template' stating 'can only use dialog-template with 'Text' or 'Mixed' types

Here's the concept i'm using

`text (URL) {
  description (The website address of the game.)
}`

Comment: I updated the original post with some more context.

Comment: Try modifying the param type in your layout-macro-def to viv.core.Text

Comment: I start receiving errors, `java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null`

Comment: It might be best to raise a ticket through the Bixby Studio for the java.lang.NullPointerException